# How do I disable Universal Links on iOS9?

Tags: ios, nsuseractivity

I try to create a NSUserActivity category that it doesn't work, but is impracticable.

Is there a way to disable other app's universal links on my app?

When user click the link go to another app in my app, how can I to know the timing?

Comment: Is TransportLayer->NSArbitraryLoad value in plist is YES or NO?

Comment: Are you mean NSAppTransportSecurity -> NSAllowsArbitraryLoads? It is YES

Comment: It doesn't work, because I have many http requests. I think it doesn't solve my problem. Anyway, thank you for your answer.